# Compensate loss of falling speed when using rb.drag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game with ball physics and an FPS camera. I'm using rb.drag and rb.angularDrag to slow my player down in certain circumstances (eg.: while on air, while braking/crouching). Problem is, it works too well as it also slows down my player's falling speed. How do I make my player fall normally while using rb.drag?

Notes:

- I've tested using rb.mass. This made controling the player worse.
- I've tried `rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * -rb.drag*gravityForce);`, but falling still felt off. Either I fell so fast i could barely jump, or the player still fell at a constant speed, without accelerating.

My movement code:

```
void Start()
    { 
        DistanceToTheGround = GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.extents.y;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Input
        moveFwrd = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        moveSide = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        // Player Jump
        onGround = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, DistanceToTheGround + 0.1f);
        if (onGround)
        {
            rb.drag = 0f;
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(jumpKey))
            {
                rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            rb.drag = 2f;
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * -rb.drag*6f);
        }

        // Braking
        if (Input.GetKey(brakeKey))
        {
            rb.drag = brakeForce;
        }
    }

    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        
        // Player Movement
        movement = cam.transform.right * moveFwrd + cam.transform.forward * moveSide;
        movement.y =0;
        movement = movement.normalized;

        rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to not use drag in scenarios like this. You can recreate a similar formula to the drag and apply it on the X and Y axis separately. In that case you'd set drag in the rigidbody to 0, then make your own drag variables. How you implement that varies by situation. I tend to manipulate velocity directly rather than adding forces so that I have more control of exactly what the velocity is. You should also only do physics stuff in FixedUpdate, so you should save your jump input in update and execute in fixed update as well.